# How can I generate more coins while mining on PoS?

Tags: mining-reward, proof-of-stake

I couldn't find the specifics on how would one get more coins with PoS.

I understand that with PoW one gets more coins by having more hashing power and running software like `cgminer`.

With PoS, I need to have more coins, and… what else? Just have the client open? If that's the case, it's kind of risky, isn't it? I mean I would have to have my private keys in an online machine?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have to have client with all your coins open with your private keys and have it sitting on online machine.

See Proof Of Stake Details section for [NXT](https://nextcoin.org/index.php?topic=104.0)

Answer (score 0):

well the even more risky aspect of POS is simply losing funds due to EDIT bank run when  the stake prover signs multiple chains and all coin owners run for exits, coins loosing value due to dump when attacker's premine matures etc.

these risks cannot be prevented even by following all best practices and keeping your machine 100% secure

EDIT: tl;dr this is why in POS, losing funds due keeping them online is a tiny tiny and trivial issue compared to other possible issues